# Empty result in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get query result from my model and use it in view. I don't know why but my result is empty. Can you look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Controller:

```
    $peugeot = $this->input->post('peugeot');
    $citroen = $this->input->post('Citroen C-Elysee');
    $nissan= $this->input->post('Nissan Evalia');
    $renault = $this->input->post('Renault Trafic 9-os');
    $this->load->model('Edit_model');
    $this->Edit_model->peugeot($peugeot);
    if($peugeot)
    {
        $result = $this->Edit_model->peugeot($peugeot);
        $data['result'] = $result;
    }
```

Model:

```
    public function peugeot($peugeot)
    {
        $this->db->like('model', $peugeot, 'after'); 
        $query = $this->db->get('cars');
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

View:

```
if($peugeot)
{
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing SQL before returning result? That way you can confirm query does return results.

Comment: ofc, [link](http://i.imgur.com/C1er7sV.png)

Comment: In you model code, try doing var_dump($this->db->last_query()); That will show if it matches what you exactly looking for.

Comment: string(61) "SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `model` LIKE 'Peugeot%' ESCAPE '!'" string(61) "SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `model` LIKE 'Peugeot%' ESCAPE '!'"

Comment: I think something is wrong with my IF in controller, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda strange, but It works

I've changed my controller into this

```
        $data['peugeot'] = $this->input->post('peugeot');
    $data['citroen'] = $this->input->post('citroen');
    $data['nissan'] = $this->input->post('nissan');
    $data['renault'] = $this->input->post('renault');
    $this->load->model('Edit_model');
    if($data['peugeot'])
    {
        $this->Edit_model->peugeot($data['peugeot']);
        $result = $this->Edit_model->peugeot($data['peugeot']);
        $data['result'] = $result;
        $this->load->view('content/editprocess',$data);
    }
```